# Android Lollipop HEVC sample

Tags: android, media-player, android-5.0-lollipop, hevc, h.265

The following link is showing new features for H.265 High Efficiency Video Coding (HEVC) for optimized encoding and decoding. But, I can not find any sample for using this api.

Is there any example or code sample available ?

[Android Lollipop new API](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#Camera)

Comment: As far as i know, this only means that HEVC support is present on all devices as of Android Lollipop, and HEVC is a lot better than e.g. AVC/H.264, thus "optimized encoding and decoding". It should then be usable with the APIs MediaPlayer and MediaCodec.

Answer (score 2):

this is a good sample, [vecio/MediaCodecDemo](https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo)  ,for me to learn about MediaCodec, MediaFormat and MediaExtractor. You can try to build it in API level 21, only API level 21 or higher supports HEVC.

Comment: Video is playing but not the audio. Can you please help me to find it?